# Angular ngForm wrapped elements?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

is there an angular way to get input elements wrapped into a `ngForm` directive?
(I need to use ngForm, this is into a asp.net form)

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('formCtrl', function($scope){

  $scope.formFields;
  $scope.model={
  
    "text": 'simple text',
    "number": 1,
    "textarea": 'lsadij isdajo\n dasjojoisajijsdaojsdaio jioasdj'
    
  };
  
  $scope.getNgFormInputs = function(e){
  
      $scope.formInfo = $scope.myFrm
      $scope.formFields = angular.noop //??? is it possible to get wrapped inputs?
  
  }


})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="formCtrl">
    
    <div ng-bind="model.text"></div>
    <div ng-bind="model.number"></div>
    <pre ng-bind="model.textarea"></pre>
    
    <ng-form name='myFrm'>
      
      <input type="text" ng-model="model.text"><br>
      
      <input type="text" ng-model="model.number"><br>
      
      <textarea ng-model="model.textarea"></textarea><br>
      
      <button ng-click="getNgFormInputs($event)" role="submit">Save</button>
      
      </ng-form>


  {{formInfo}}<hr>
  {{formFields}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Tks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, at a higher level? This sounds like a XY problem to me.

Comment: Yes, it maybe a XY problem. This code is just a concept. In my real world, (A) $scope.model is a larger object and I'm updating part of it. (B) Time's running out, so I've hard coded form elements instead of compiling them using a directive that gets a model[prop] array attribute (it would solve my problem). (C) So, to save time, I don't want to write again and again the [{prop: val}] that's already wrapped into my ngForm. Neither I wan't to use jQuery. Codeless, always. Does this clarifies? Tks"

Comment: @JBNizet, could you elaborate what's on your mind? There are some scenarios Syed's answer do not apply. Tks

Comment: What's on my mind is that doing DOM manipulation in Angular is usually a design smell. You should work on the domain, not on the graphical components in the DOM. But since I don't have any idea of what you're actually trying to achieve, it's impossible to give a good advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it has if i understand you correctly. For reference see this
https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-dynamic-angular-forms-with-ngrepeat-and-ngform

More specific : For quick : https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-dynamic-angular-forms-with-ngrepeat-and-ngform#validation-using-ngform

Comment: tks, the missing name attr in input elements made me not to realize it. simple line of code and I'm good to go: $scope.formFields = Object.keys($scope.myNgForm).filter(x =>  (!/^\$/.test(x)) )

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Syed, the reference solved my problem.

I suggest people to read my own comment in thw answer.

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('formCtrl', function($scope){

  $scope.formFields;
  $scope.model={
  
    "text": 'simple text',
    "number": 1,
    "textarea": 'lsadij isdajo\n dasjojoisa \n jijsdaojsdaio jioasdj'
    
  };
  
  $scope.formFieldsAndValues = {}
  
  $scope.getNgFormInputs = function(e){
  
      
      $scope.formFields = keys = Object.keys($scope.myFrm).filter(x =>  (!/^\$/.test(x)) )
      keys.forEach(x=> $scope.formFieldsAndValues[x] = $scope.myFrm[x].$viewValue)
  
  }


})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="formCtrl">
    
    <div ng-bind="model.text"></div>
    <div ng-bind="model.number"></div>
    <pre ng-bind="model.textarea"></pre>
    
    <ng-form name='myFrm'>
      
      <input type="text" ng-model="model.text" name="text"><br>
      
      <input type="text" ng-model="model.number" name="number"><br>
      
      <textarea type="text" ng-model="model.textarea" name="textarea"></textarea><br>
      
      <button ng-click="getNgFormInputs($event)" role="submit">Save</button>
      
      </ng-form>
<hr>
form fields:
  {{formFields}}
    <hr>
field,value pairs:
  {{formFieldsAndValues}}
  </div>
</div>
```